# How to add more nodes to the default Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm learning Elasticsearch and try to add more nodes into my default ES cluster.
I followed [the official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html) (my ES version is 7.17.10), but I am confused about how to "**Set up a new Elasticsearch instance.** as the first step to add a node.

Comment: So simply saying download Elasticsearch twice, and rename each of them `node1` and `node2` accordingly. Then inside the `elasticsearch.yml` file make name changes accordingly, and you will have two Elasticsearch instances

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov I installed it with `sudo apt install elasticsearch`, so if I install it again, it will replace the existing "instance". What should I do?

Comment: before installing another one, rename the previously installed one. (rename its folder name)